# Joomla 1.5 500 errors on all menu items

Tags: joomla1.5

I have a website that was working just fine for a long time but out of the blue, the main menu off the template and a module menu are all giving 500 errors.

You are still able to grab articles by their ID's and view them.
You can also create a new menu items and that new menu item will work just fine.

Why would all menu links just break but you can create new ones and they work? 
We have over 40-50 different menu's depending on what pages you’re on. I would hate to have to re-due this whole process and instead fine a fix to it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be apache mod_rewrite that is not loaded.

Have you touched to apache (or any web server) configuration ?

```
Administration panel > Menu > Site -> Global Configuration -> Site: Search Engine Friendly URLs to No
```

If your website works, then the mod_rewrite module is your problem.